# Clear browser history in Asp.net MVC3 using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, browser, browser-history

i am using mvc3 and at certain action i want  to clear browser history using c# code . Can anybody help me i am in great trouble .

Comment: You want to clear the history of the client's web browser from your remote web site?  Or are you running something locally to the client machine?

Answer (score 2):

My apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but you cannot clear a client's browsing history from server-side code.  The browser history (bugs aside) is normally protected very heavily.

Answer (score 1):

You can't clear a remote browsers history. If you want to clear your local browsers history in code, just delete the files where it stores it's temporary files, this may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_Internet_Files depending on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can clear is the client cookies by expiring them... but you can't touch browsers history.

As far as local computer is concerned you can simply delete the temporary files browser use, but remember some browsers store everything from history to form login data in a SQLLite DB so you may end up deleting everything.